# jQuery click() event not firing on AJAX loaded HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

the subject is pretty descriptive of my problem, I am assuming it won't work this way, is there a way to make it work? (workaround)?

Here is the code that is loaded via AJAX:

```
<div>
<div id="s0frame" class="sframe"></div>
<div id="s1frame" class="sframe"></div>
<div id="s2frame" class="sframe"></div>
<div id="s3frame" class="sframe"></div>
<div id="s4frame" class="sframe"></div>
<div id="s5frame" class="sframe"></div>
<div id="chatframe" class="chat alpha60"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my click event:

```
$('.sframe').bind('click', function() { 
    var seat_number = this.id.match(/\d/g);
    alert(seat_number); 
});
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Do this.

```
 $(document).on("click",".sframe",function(e){
 var seat_number = this.id.match(/\d/g);
 alert(seat_number); 
 });
```

or

```
 $(document).delegate(".sframe","click",function(e){
 var seat_number = this.id.match(/\d/g);
 alert(seat_number); 

 });
```

Edit:

**As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate().**

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, so use its replacement `.on()` for newer versions

Comment: Thank you works great, since you answered first I will choose you!

Comment: When I try .on() instead of .live(), it does not fire. (edit: is that because I am using 1.7?)

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '.sframe', function(){
  var seat_number = this.id.match(/\d/g);
  alert(seat_number); 
});`

Comment: It's because `.sframe` is part of the AJAX response and .on() must applied to an object that remains on the page so it can monitor its contents.

Comment: Downvoted because of the use of `live()`. It is deprecated and its use should not be promoted anymore (even before `on()`, `delegate()` was recommended instead of `live()`). If the answer is fixed I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @bazmegakapa. Thanks for pointing out .I have changed the answer.

Comment: @AngelWorkz Thanks, I have removed the downvote (the `on()` variation is still incorrect though, see 3nigma's answer).

Comment: Also I would recommend changing it from `$(document).on('click', '.sframe', function());` to `$('a').on('click', '.sframe', function());` because you don't want it to go through every element in the document just the a links.

Comment: Necromnius, that defeats the *entire* benefit of .on()'s event scoping. Your suggestion would cause every <a> on the page to be bound with an event, whereas simply binding to the document and listening for clicks that come from '.sframe' as they bubble up requires only one listener. Further, the example used divs being clicked (caution, original asker, may not work on mobile) so binding to 'a' in this limited example would actually do nothing.

Answer (score 16):

you have to re-attach the event handlers to the dynamically added elements into the DOM. `.live` method was used widely but now its deprecated. In jQuery version 1.7+ you can use [**`.on`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or alternatively you can use [**`.delegate`**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$(document).on("click",".sframe",function(e){

});
```

using delegate

```
$(document).delegate(".sframe","click",function(e){

});
```

Comment: this was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks @3nigma. The first one method worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are calling that .bind() function after that markup is loaded onto the page, you need to use another function like .live() or preferably if using a recent version of jQuery, .on() because .bind() only targets DOM elements already present when run whereas .live() and .on() give you different scope options for keeping track of elements added to the page.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click','sframe', function() { 
    var seat_number = this.id.match(/\d/g);
    alert(seat_number); 
});
```