# jquery function after infinite scroll event

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll, infinite

I'm trying to load the comment form dynamically into their corresponding posts. What I have so far works for the first 6 posts that are loaded on the initial load. It's after the initial load that I'm running into problems. I need to be able to get this code to work on the remaining posts that are paginated and shown with an infinite scroll event. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers,
Mike

Commenform div in comment.php

```
<div id="commentform-<?php the_ID(); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="display: none"></div>
```

Comment form being called for in shortcodes.php

```
$output.='<div id="swap_comments-'.get_the_ID().'"rel="'.get_the_ID().'">'.comments_template('/comment.php').'</div>';
```

Comment form being handled in plugins.js

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
var commentscon = jQuery("div[id^='commentform']");
jQuery("div[id^='swap_comments']").append(commentscon);
jQuery.each(jQuery("div[id^='swap_comments']"),function(){
var CurrectDiv=jQuery(this);
CurrectDiv.find('div').filter(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).attr('rel')==CurrectDiv.attr('rel'))
    {
       jQuery(this).show(); 
    }
        });
});
});
```

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272438/jquery-click-event-not-firing-on-ajax-loaded-html-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery .on() which has replaced .live()

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: so i would write it out like this jQuery(window).on(function()?

Comment: No, use it like this

jQuery("div[id^='swap_comments']").on(function(){});

Comment: Hmm...just tried that and now none of the comment forms are showing up..thoughts?

Comment: can you please write your code under a single $(window).ready(function(){})? and write the code for appending after the .on event handler ?

Comment: Hi there..first off i'm not terribly familiar with jQuery thus the request for help..secondly i've edited my question and hopefully that's what you are asking for. Regards

Comment: Nope. I was asking to merge your code frome two jQuery(window).ready(function() {}) into one, since the window only loads once, hence no point writing two different functions.

Secondly, what i was trying to tell is instead of using jquery.each for finding all "div[id^='swap_comments']", you could simply attach the .on() event handler on to it, so that every time it loads, the function would execute

Comment: okay..i took care of that in the question. also when i made the changes you recommended the forms disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to assign function to dynamicly added elements.

Comment: i'm using 1.7.2, isn't .live deprecated?