# Anchor links are not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have two type of anchor link one which utilize ajax and other which directly call particular url

Anchor links are not working after ajax call .Everything  is running fine using that code but the problem is page has some other anchor links which stop working after the ajax call but the other links which are using ajax call are working fine.Interesting part is when I press ESC key the anchor link which are not working start working.
I am making the ajax call in that way :

```
$("#submit1").bind('click', function(e){          
    SubmitFormData();
});

function SubmitFormData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo Router::Url('/'); ?>Items/edit",
        data: $("#ItemEditForm").serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        start: $("#MaskedDiv").loadOverStart(),
        success: function(response) {
            // hide loading image
            $("#MaskedDiv").loadOverStop();
            $("#modal_window_container").html(response);
            closeDialog();
            showMessage();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: show your html code..

Comment: Probably the same issue resolved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272438/jquery-click-event-not-firing-on-ajax-loaded-html-elements

Comment: Define "not working."  What are those anchor tags supposed to do?  What changes about the anchor tags following the AJAX call?  It _sounds_ like the problem is that you're adding new DOM elements (new anchor tags) and need to re-bind some event to them (see @lotsofcode's comment), but I don't see where you're even binding an event to them in the first place.