# Close link not working and opening modal window instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have an 'a' tag, that when clicked, removes the thumbnail from the gallery by calling a jquery click event. But if I dynamically add a thumbnail image and then remove it on the same page without refreshing, the click event doesn't get triggered. It triggers the modal window to pop up (as if I was clicking on the image). Then if I press the 'x' (to close) the modal window THEN triggers the jquery click event to remove the image. It works fine on non dynamically added thumbs or if the page has been refreshed.

```js
$('a.close').click(function () {
    
    var imageId = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post(
            '/ManageSpaces/RemoveImage',
            { id: imageId }
        );
    $(this).parents('li').remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="row">
  <ul id="sortable">
    @foreach (var image in Model.Images.OrderBy(i => i.Ordering)) {
    <li id="@image.YogaSpaceImageId" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 imagethumbs" data-yogaspaceid="@Model.YogaSpaceId">

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a id="@image.YogaSpaceImageId" class="close" href="#">×</a>
        @{ var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image.ImageThumbnail); var thumbSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64); var base64Modal = Convert.ToBase64String(image.Image); var imgSrcModal = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64Modal);
        var imageId = "pop" + image.YogaSpaceImageId; var imagesourceId = "imagesource" + image.YogaSpaceImageId; }
        <a class="image" id="@imageId" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          <img id="@imagesourceId" src="@thumbSrc" data-imagesrc="@imgSrcModal" alt="image not found" width="203" height="136" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>...</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a>  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>
    }
  </ul>
  <div class="modal fade" id="imageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          <img id="modalPreview" alt="image not found" width="355" height="355" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this snippet of js adds the new thumbnail when a user selects a new image and then appends it to a ul list.

```js
var listItem = 
        "<li id=\"" + responseText.YogaSpaceImageId + "\" class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-4 imagethumbs\" data-yogaspaceid=" + $("#HiddenYogaSpaceId").val() + ">" +
            "<div class=\"thumbnail\">" +
            "<a id=\"" + responseText.YogaSpaceImageId + "\" class=\"close\" href=\"#\">×</a>" +
                "<a class=\"image\" id=\"" + imageId + "\" href=\"\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\">" +
                    "<img id=\"" + imagesourceId + "\" src=\"" + thumbSrc + "\" data-imagesrc=\"" + imgSrcModal + "\" alt=\"image not found\" width=\"203\" height=\"136\" />" +
                "</a>" +
                "<div class=\"caption\">" +
                    "<h3>Thumbnail label</h3>" +
                    "<p>...</p>" +
                    "<p><a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" role=\"button\">Button</a> <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-default\" role=\"button\">Button</a></p>" +
                "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</li>";

    var $li = $(listItem);
    $('ul#sortable').append($li);
```

Comment: You either need to add the close event handler when you add the new element dynamically, or use a delegate (e.g., `$('.a_close_parent').on('click', '.close', func...)`).

Comment: can you provide a better example please!?

Comment: This has been answered many, many (many) times. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272438/jquery-click-event-not-firing-on-ajax-loaded-html-elements

Comment: I tried $("div.thumbnail").on("click", ".close", function (event) {
    var imageId = $(this).attr('id');
}); but had the same result

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't do anything in the function body.

Comment: ya, I'm just trying to get the event to trigger first, before I add all the necessary code in the function. I also tried adding another class (.close.removethumb) because it looks like bootstrap has a close class, and the bootstrap modal is using it and there  might be interference here. But .close.removethumb isn't working either

Comment: Use `console.log('test');` in the function body with the Javascript console open so you can see it working.

Comment: I'm setting breakpoints so I know I'm not triggering the event

Comment: This is a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/s89qdno4/

Comment: Also, it appears that you're *adding* `div.thumbnail` when the `.close` is added, it needs to be a node that's a parent of `.imagethumbs` (or something that was present in the dom that's both a parent of where `div.thumbnail` will be appended and was present when the original event is added). That's how delegates work. The other option is add the jQuery event handler after the content is appended to the dom. What you're doing in the question, though, translates to *add this event handler to any matching elements*; what's missing is *now and in the future*. Delegates approximate that last part.

Comment: Here's the second (add the event handler with the element append) option: http://jsfiddle.net/s89qdno4/1/

Comment: ah I see! I have to use a tag that was there before the new stuff is added. I tried $("ul#sortable").on("click", ".close.removethumb", function (event) {
    var imageId = $(this).attr('id');
}); and it's now triggering on the newly added stuff, but now the modal window is popping up everytime I remove the thumb

Comment: You need to [stop propagation of further events](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/451969). I usually use a `return false;` at the end of the event handler, which does both prevent default and stop propagation.

Comment: I tried both return false and event.preventDefault and the modal is still popping up.

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation()`. `event.preventDefault()` doesn't stop propagation; what it seems to be is that your modal is being triggered by the click in a containing element to the X button. Another option would be to use the element's click event instead of the inline attribute `data-modal` and check if the event has been stopped with [`event.isPropationStopped()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.isPropagationStopped/)

Comment: I figured it out. I had another click event tied to the same type of click event for the removal of the thumb. it was on a click event from a 'li' tag. I fixed. thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

$('a.close') selects currently available elements, if you add a new element you need to call your jQuery on it as well.

```
$(element).yourOriginalQuery
```

Comment: what do you mean "you need to call your jQuery on it"?

Comment: what is "yourOriginalQuery"?

Comment: It's the query in your question.